# TypeScript Type Inference with Intersection of Generic Types

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics, inferred-type

I have a use case where I have a composable object, that should (not) work with some functions, depending on what it has been composed of. The composition is done using type intersection.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
type A<T> = { a: T }
type B<T> = { b: (val: T) => T }

const shouldWork = {
  a: 'str',
  b: (val: string) => val.toUpperCase(),
  someOtherProp: 'foo'
}

const shouldFail = {
  a: 'str',
  b: (val: number) => 42
}

function test<T extends A<???> & B<???>>(obj: T): T {
  return {
    ...obj,
    a: obj.b(obj.a)
  }
}

const res1 = test(shouldWork);
// res1 should be typeof shouldWork, i.e. A & B & { someOtherProp: string }
console.log(res1.a); // "STR"
console.log(res1.someOtherProp); // "foo"

const res2 = test(shouldFail); // should fail because A<string> and B<number> don't match
```

I've tried using `test<T extends A<any> & B<any>>`, but this of course will allow any combination of generic types.

Then I tried adding an extra type `S` to ensure that both generics are the same: `test<S, T extends A<S> & B<S>>`. But this will fail because *"Types of parameters 'val' and 'val' are incompatible. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'"*

After some more tries I found something that does work as expected:

```
function test<S, T extends A<S> & B<S> = A<S> & B<S>>(obj: T): T { ... }
const res1 = test<string>(shouldWork);
const res2 = test<string>(shouldFail); // throws error: Types of parameters 'val' and 'val' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

But as you can see, it's hard to read and a lot to write, especially when the intersection consists of more types.

Is there some easier way to get this done?

Comment: Why do you even need `T`?  You should use just `S` (renamed to `T` [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbdv8w)).  Even the example use case can't guarantee that the returned value is of the right type.  If the intersection consists of a lot of types then give it an alias like `type I<T>= A<T> & B<T> & C<T> & ...` and then just `function test<T>(obj: I<T>)`.  If these suggestions don't match your use case, you might want to elaborate and provide a [mcve] that shows why.

Comment: But now you return `A<T> & B<T>`, which is not what I want. I want to return the same type as used for the function argument. Example: If you have `type X = A & B & C`, then `test` should return `A & B & C`, even if `test` only needs `A & B` to work. I'll add an example to the question

Comment: Okay, then does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXkvoW) work better for you?

Comment: If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what is missing.

Comment: I guess, you're a magician. All my tests have passed. Let me try to explain your solution: *"function `test` takes an argument that can be anything (generic type `O` without constraints) **and** it must implement `I<T>` (which is equal to `A<T> & B<T>`), and the function returns that type"*. What I don't understand: Why does `test<S, T extends A<S> & B<S>>(obj: T): T` not work? Maybe you could write a short answer and earn your well deserved points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little "iffy", but one way to achieve the inference you want is like this:

```
function test<O, T>(obj: O & A<T> & B<T>): O {
    return {
        ...obj,
        a: obj.b(obj.a)
    }
}
```

When you want the compiler to infer a type parameter `X` from a call to a function `func(param)` where `param` is of type `P` and the call signature for `func` is like  `<X>(param: F<X>) => any`, the compiler will plug `P` in for `F<X>` to get candidates for `X`.

If the call signature involves an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) like `<X>(param: F<X> & G<X>) => void`, the compiler will tend to plug `P` in for *both* `F<X>` *and* `G<X>` to get candidates... even though it would be fine (and sometimes desirable) to do that for only one of them.

So with `test(obj)` of call signature `<O, T>(obj: O & A<T> & B<T>) => O`, the compiler will tend to match `O` with `typeof obj` to get the candidate for `O`, and then also match `A<T>` and `B<T>` to `typeof obj` to get the candidate for `T`.  If `obj` is not a valid `A<T> & B<T>` the inference will fail.  And you can use `O` to represent the actual type of `obj` without widening it to `A<T> & B<T>`.

So this behaves the way you want:

```
const res1 = test(shouldWork); // okay
const res2 = test(shouldFail); // error
// -------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '{ a: string; b: (val: number) => number; }' is not assignable to
//  parameter of type '{ a: string; b: (val: number) => number; } & A<number> & B<number>'.
```

---

If that hadn't worked, you could have gotten similar behavior by using a single unconstrained type parameter `O` and have the parameter `obj` be of a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
function test<O>(obj: O extends (A<infer T> & B<infer T>) ? O : never): O {
    return {
        ...obj,
        a: obj.b(obj.a)
    }
}

const res1 = test(shouldWork); // okay
const res2 = test(shouldFail); // error\
// -------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '{ a: string; b: (val: number) => number; }' \
// is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

This works because the compiler will tend to plug the type of the parameter `P` in for the parameter `X` in a conditional type like `X extends ...`, and so `typeof obj` is the candidate for `O`, which then gets checked against `A<infer T> & B<infer T>`.  If a valid `T` is found, then `obj` will be checked against `O` again, which is no problem.  If no valid `T` is found, then `obj` will be checked against `never`, which is probably not going to work.  It's a bit more complicated but has similar behavior (with a less understandable error message).

---

As for why the following doesn't work:

```
declare function test<O extends A<T> & B<T>, T>(obj: O): O;
```

The problem is that there is no *inference site* for `T`.  The compiler can use `typeof obj` to infer `O`, but when it checks `T`, it's stuck.  You might expect that the compiler could infer `T` from `O`'s [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `A<T> & B<T>`, but generic constraints are not used as inference sites this way.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) for an old suggestion to support this.  Instead of implementing such a feature, they [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234#issuecomment-223627422) that people infer from intersections in exactly the way I have done at the beginning of this answer.

Anyway with no inference site for `T`, the compiler falls back to `unknown` for it.  And then `O` is constrained to `A<unknown> & B<unknown>`, and that is unlikely to work.  So everything falls apart.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFQHxQLxQN5QIYC4oJQC+AsAFCiRQBCiK6WARvgBQBu2ANvggJRopCpMuQDGAewB2AZ2BRpAC3EBXTgBMA6uIBOAazSZyUYznwByWdrMAaIyeZR2XfJYCWkgOb9UKDpwB0wOIAqmCQ2gDC2NIQLLy2ZCZQovgAjAAM6eTCYlKy8kqqagBi2K6cBhh2xnhQFsBWCUkOTtxQksoAtowQ2t4oACwATNnkY2QAZsqSosCuUlDAELJwAPLWBEgs4owAVvirUABksHTHNHS8B4aJJtoQwMrakjdJSf4fO7tNbzX4X-5GNs9v5sLxqsRRiIyBIZHJ7tJUgYlrIWIoVOotHpeABuKAAenxUHEumwIFycKgCKGyOWwDRhXUpXKuIJRN62h05EJUAAtPyBYKBSgAH5i8US7lEmDaDxdCCSOTiCaLcDQMxYWpuTx4lp+fAdbq9frtLo9bR4ohmKCuaTtcRyaLSVweSTYRicaBBKXGMDYbTYToPXrElWUdWalwNdweXWsfWmo19ASJ82W87wQ3mlAnWhZ3pIMz+cZuoPSP2iaAAWR0EAi4k6YE4rlE2CWahuEKmMzmCxRwDWWy+1wgAA8lpI1HaWPB3BMQ8hzrQ5wukPwAPxQQ4GiBsY3XKq3X73R7PV6-N4ffxfH4Xky1AFAgFgiFJYRv8ZJWH5BFI9D9hkMU0HRdFZHkSTJCFv3hZYaX-OlAKKZlODA9ltE5bQAB0IR5IU8P5UUJSInDpVleVFVDVUqA1Ux5GjHUoD1ZxU2NFN8wtYhrWwo82RtO1JAdHBpGdV13U9RZxCgP0AyDJZtEo8M6kkXdejMKFyFLZYK2gAA5B0sX0Q8kjUCBRE4f1oG7WZ5hefs1igMcJynU5F1zOgNmQYF9i3K4txxT8TGgqllj-RYEPRIoDNxKC8hg6Q4LC1EIqZMoUP8sgiCAA)